# CLion jetbrains-toolbox: error trying to exec 'cc1plus'

Tags: c++, linux, g++, jetbrains, clion

При попытке компиляции из терминала CLion  получаю сообщение

```
jetbrains-toolbox: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: Нет такого файла или каталога
```

При этом той же командой из системного терминала все работает без ошибок

Подскажите что ему не нравится

[image: CLion compile error]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: видимо они поменяли переменные окружения, например, PATH. Сравнение вывода env в обеих консолях покажет виновника

Comment: Подсказать, где находится бесплатный переводчик?

Comment: @PinkTux Вопрос не в переводе сообщения на русский, а в том, почему он пытается исполнить cc1plus

Comment: @KoVadim сейчас сравним, спасибо за версию

Comment: @KoVadim PATH не изменен, добавлены некоторые переменные, но PATH идентичен (ссылка https://goo.gl/LqdYKM)

Comment: @Trinks мне помог запуск приложения не через jetbrains-toolbox, а прям именно clion